# Laravel Remember Me functionality

Tags: php, laravel

please someone guide me with the laravel remember me functionality.!
how does laravel Remember me Token works.?
1. Is it used to save the username and password so (If remember me is Clicked) and the user logouts of the application when the user comes back after certain amount of time his username and password fields will be save in the form. Example Facebook.
2. Or Remember me just forces the user to be logged in for certain amount of time and if the user logouts everything is clear..! other wise it will keep the user logged in for the specific time we specified.

Answer (score 6):

The remember-me cookie [contains](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/66d028ad2ef1251d3215880227a5f94168280201/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L458) the user's ID, a random token (which is stored in the `users` table), and the user's *hashed* password. If present and valid, the user doesn't need to log in; they are deemed already authenticated.

It is set as a cookie with the `forever` expiration, which, despite the name, Laravel defines as five years. If a user logs out, [their remember token is changed so the old cookie is no longer valid](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/66d028ad2ef1251d3215880227a5f94168280201/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L481).

No pre-filling of the login form occurs.

Comment: but the thing is i cannot see any difference when i click remember or without clicking the remember me it works the same way i cant find any difference is there anyway i can try to see if there is any difference.?
i tried logout closing the browser etc etc any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Laravel's built-in login controller? Or doing `Auth::attempt` in your own code? "Remember me" is handled via a cookie, named `remember_<guard>_<random string>`.

Comment: yes i am using laravel built in login controller 
actually i m using Laravel's Auth

Comment: Isn't it extremely dangerous to store even a hashed password in the cookie? It can be (easily) cracked (with enough CPU power), right? What about storing just the random token? Wouldn't it still suffice as it is not (easily) guessable by attackers?

Comment: @milkamar Laravel encrypts cookie contents with an algorithm that is believed to be effectively uncrackable with current computing. Same sort of thing that's used to encrypt your bank transactions etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) What is the algorithm? And still, why the password - is it just because of for the hash to differ if the password is changed -> so the token won't work anymore?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption "All encrypted values are encrypted using OpenSSL and the AES-256-CBC cipher."